# PowerShell Scripts to Look for Excel files with .xls and .xlsx extensions

Tags: excel, powershell, directory

I have an already written scripts which looks for ONLY an excel file with .xls extension. Now,

1. I want the same scripts to look for either .xls or .xlsx which ever it finds in that particular location and use it......
2. The old scripts search for files in the F column only on the excel sheet/file.....This makes the search takes forever, so I would like it to search the files in the F column which ONLY have this path:root_project/Fut_DB_Projects in the E column of the excel sheet.

Pls let me know exactly where to insert it in the scripts. I'm very new to Powershell and your answers would be very much appreciated.

```
# Creating an object for the Excel COM addin

$excelfile = $args[0]
$folder = $args[1]
echo $excelfile
echo $folder

if($excelfile -ne $Null -and $excelfile.Contains(".xls") -and (Test-Path $excelfile) -eq $True)
{
    if($folder -ne $Null -And $folder.Contains("\") -and (Test-Path $folder) -eq $True)
    {
        $ExcelObject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

        # Opening the Workbook
        $ExcelWorkbook = $ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open($excelfile)

        # Opening the Worksheet by using the index (1 for the first worksheet)
        $ExcelWorksheet = $ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

        #The folder where the files will be copied/The folder which will be zipped later
        $a = Get-Date

        $targetfolder = "C:\"+$a.Month+"_"+$a.Day+"_"+$a.Year+"_"+$a.Hour+$a.Minute+$a.Second

        #Check if the folder already exists. Command Test-Path $targetfolder returns true or false.
        if(Test-Path $targetfolder)
        {
            #delete the folder if it already exists. The following command deletes a particular directory
            Remove-Item $targetfolder -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }

        #The following command is used to create a particular directory
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $targetfolder
        echo "Temp folder created"
        #Declaration of variables, COlumn value = 6 for Column F
        $row = 1
        $col = 6 

        # Read a value from the worksheet with the following command
        $filename = $ExcelWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,$col).Value2
        $filename
        #change the folder value below to specify the folder where the powershell needs to search for the filename that it reads from excel file.
        $null = ""

        # Loop through each row in the excel file.
        do
        {
            $filename = $ExcelWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,$col).Value2

            #Checking if value read from Excel is Null
            #In powershell operator for NOT EQUAL TO is -ne not <>
            if($filename -ne $Null)
            {
                $filepath = $folder+$filename
                #Check if the filepath read from excel is a real filepath OR check if the file exists.
                if(Test-Path $filepath)
                {
                    #If the file exists, move it to the folder declared above
                    # Change the below command to Move-Item if you want to Move the file and not Copy...
                    Copy-Item $filepath $targetfolder
                }
                else
                {
                    #$Allfiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder
                    #You add the folders to the following list that you want the script to skip as it searches
                    #for the files through directory and its subdirectories
                    #eg. $xdir = @("Folder1","Folder2","Folder3")
                    $xdir = @("Tables","Views","Update","Synonyms","BES","ADTLTransit","Fut_DB_Jobs","Triggers","Scripts")
                    $remove = [string]::join("|",$xdir)

                    $Allfiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder | ? { $_.DirectoryName -notmatch $remove} 
                    Write-Host -Fore Yellow ("Looking through subfolders now")

                    foreach ($file in $Allfiles)
                    {
                        $testpath = $file.FullName
                        if($testpath.Contains($filename))
                        {
                            Write-Host -Fore Yellow ("Found the file in a subfolder at location:" + $testpath)
                            Move-Item $testpath $targetfolder
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            #incrementing the row variable by 1 to move to the next available row in excel.
            $row = $row + 1
        }
        #while condition evaluates if value read from the excel is null. If null, then the loop breaks.
        while($filename -ne $Null)

        # Important: The object needs to quit and the variables release, otherwise
        # an Excel.exe will remain open.
        $ExcelObject.Quit()

        $ExcelObject = $null
        $ExcelWorkbook = $null
        $ExcelWorksheet = $null

        [GC]::Collect()
        do
        {
        }
        while((Test-Path -path $targetfolder) -ne $True)
        $targetfolderinfo = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $targetfolder | Measure-Object
        $targetfolderfilecount = $targetfolderinfo.count

        if($targetfolderfilecount -ne 0)
        {
            #Following command calls the function to zip all the files moved from source folder to target folder
            $directory = [IO.DirectoryInfo] $targetfolder

            If ($directory -eq $null)
            {
                Throw "Value cannot be null: directory"
            }

            Write-Host ("Creating zip file for folder (" + $directory.FullName + ")...")    
            [IO.DirectoryInfo] $parentDir = $directory.Parent    
            [string] $zipFileName

            If ($parentDir.FullName.EndsWith("\") -eq $true)
            {
                # e.g. $parentDir = "C:\"
                $zipFileName = $parentDir.FullName + $directory.Name + ".zip"
            }
            Else
            {
                $zipFileName = $parentDir.FullName + "\" + $directory.Name + ".zip"
            }

            If (Test-Path $zipFileName)
            {
                Remove-Item $zipFileName -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }

            Set-Content $zipFileName ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))

            $shellApp = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
            $zipFile = $shellApp.NameSpace($zipFileName)

            If ($zipFile -eq $null)
            {
                Throw "Failed to get zip file object."
            }

            [int] $expectedCount = (Get-ChildItem $directory -Force -Recurse).Count
            $expectedCount += 1 # account for the top-level folder

            $zipFile.CopyHere($directory.FullName)

            Write-Host -Fore Green ("Successfully created zip file for folder (" `
                + $directory.FullName + ").")
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host -Fore Red ("There are no files to be zipped")
        }

        [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(10000)
        Remove-Item $targetfolder -recurse
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host -Fore Red ("Target folder path not specified correctly")
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host -Fore Red ("Excel file path not specified") 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the first if to this

```
if($excelfile -ne $Null -and $excelfile -like "*.xls*" -and (Test-Path $excelfile) -eq $True)
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I tried it and it still didn't pick my excile file with the .xlsx extension.

Comment: fixed in the answer, i left out a *